# How to bind a GridView after calling a WebMethod?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, webmethod

At the moment I am doing drag & drop to GridView rows which sends the new row order to a *WebMethod* in order to update the database according to these new values.

So, how can I update the GridView in the web form after calling the WebMethod? Considering that I can't access to any of the webform elements from a WebMethod.

Web Method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void GridViewCarriersReorders(string Reorder)
{
    Boolean result;
    string[] ListID = Reorder.Split('|');
    transactions tr = new transactions();
    result = tr.updateLcrPriorities(ListID);
    //updateGridViewCarriers(); //SOMETHING LIKE THIS IS NEEDED TO DO THE BINDING
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help and comprehension.

**UPDATE**: This is how I am calling the webmethod:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "lcrP.aspx/GridViewCarriersReorders",
    data: '{"Reorder":"' + strorder + '"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (msg) {
        $.jGrowl("The Carriers priority was successfully updated", { theme: "succeeded" });
    }
})
```

Comment: Have you looked at using Javascript to perform an Ajax postback, JQuery.Delay() or setTimeout?

Comment: @Lloyd Actually, I am calling the webmethod by using ajax. But I can't see how I would use it to update the GridView. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried using javascript to do this. Go through [this post](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/03/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript.html). When you get success from WebMethod, create a row and append to the GridView (it's infact a table).

Comment: @AmarPalsapure Thanks for your response. But I have no issues with doing the drag and drop to the GridView rows in the client side (by using the tableDnD jQuery plug). And the webmethod actually updates the DB flawlessly. However, I need to know how to update the GridView after doing this.

Comment: @AmarPalsapure response answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put an UpdatePanel around the gridview, you can call a postback only for it:

```
success: function (msg) {
        $.jGrowl("The Carriers priority was successfully updated", { theme: "succeeded" });
        __doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '');
    }
```

**EDIT:**
As you found by yourself, i missed writing that in the OnLoad event you should force databind of the grid:

```
void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnLoad(e);
    myGrid.DataBind();
}
```

As an alternative, if your grid is bound to a xDataSource control you can disable the viewstate of the grid, and if it will be forced to DataBind at each postback.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it doesn't quite work. I've just debugged it and this is the current behaviour: 1) Call the WebMethod and updates the database with the new values. 2) Performs the postback that you suggested. 3) Reloads the webform with the previous state, I mean, with the old GridView row order, although it actually made the changes in the DB. This can be confirmed by manually selecting the info. Any other idea will be highly appreciated

Comment: Eventually, I was able to do it by creating the OnLoad event for the UpdatePanel and rebinding the GridView from there. It would be cool if you could add that to the answer. Thanks a lot.